# Rewriting a limit with $\frac{\sin(3 x - \pi)}{\pi - 3 x}$ to resemble $\lim_{x\to k}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this expression for the operand of a limit expression:

$$\frac{\sin(3 x - \pi)}{\pi - 3 x}$$

I want to get something like:

$$\lim_{x \to k} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$

What a need to do achieve that?

I have applied some trigonometric equivalencies like:

$$\sin(3x - π) = \sin(3x - π + 2π) = \sin(3x + π)$$

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps variable change $z=3x-\pi$ ?

Comment: Could you give more directions to do that?

Comment: Only take, $y=3x-\pi$ this implies that $\lim \frac{\sin(3x-\pi)}{\pi-3x}=\lim \frac{\sin(y)}{-y}$, i guess that you need just this right?

Comment: What is the original limit?

Comment: Write $\lim_{x\to\frac\pi3}$.

Comment: This is the original limit: $\lim_{x \to \frac{pi}{3}}\frac{sin(3x-\pi)}{\pi-3x}$

Comment: @InfZero Then follow the suggestion laready given, assume $y=3x-\pi \to 0$ as $x \to \frac \pi 3$.